# Distinct with Limit and Skip

Tags: mongodb-query, distinct, limit

I have a collection which contains 20 Million records. Need to find distinct of one field. Which might have 10K distinct value. I want to apply to Sort , limit and skip to fetch the 1000 distinct value in one query.

I tried using aggregate query to find distinct values with limit, but it works very slow. As compared if I use distinct function, it is relatively fast, but I am not able to apply limit to the result.

This is continuously growing collection.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform `$sort` or `$limit` with `distinct` command.

Your best option is to use MongoDB Aggregation along with indexing.

Index Command:

```
db.<Collection-Name>.createIndex({"<Key-Name>": 1}, {background: true})
```

Aggregation Query:

```
db.<Collection-Name>.aggregate([
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$<Key-Name>'
        }
    },
    {
        '$sort': {
            '_id': 1  // Sort in Ascending order, `-1` for descending order 
        }
    },
    {
        '$limit': 1000
    }
])
```

Comment: I have already created Index. still query takes around 20-25 sec. Is there any ways for performance improvement.

Comment: Is your Aggregation Pipeline structure the same as what I have previded the answer? If not please give it a try with indexing and let me know the execution time.